# How to show using vue static data into modal?

Tags: vue.js

I have this couple of 'cards' with this content

```
<div class='card'>
<span>title one </span>
<button @click='open = !open'>show</button>
</div>

<div class='card'>
<span>title two </span>
<button @click='open = !open'>show</button>
</div>
```

Where in the same component I show this modal. What i need to show inside of it is if I click the first button, show title one, if I click button 2,show title 2 and so on...

What will be the best approach to do this task? (show in modal the card content)

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of things:

- `ooen` might be a typo, did you mean `open`?
- `=!` looks like a single operator but it actually means `open = !open` in this context. Put a space between the `=` and `!` to make it clear what it means.

If you want to control the visibility of two sections independently then you will need two separate data properties (`open1` and `open2`). Use `v-if` or `v-show` to control the visibility.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    open1: false,
    open2: false,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="card">
    <span v-if="open1">title 1</span>
    <button @click="open1 = !open1">toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <span v-if="open2">title 2</span>
    <button @click="open2 = !open2">toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you will have lots of these, then wrap the functionality into a separate component so you don't have to define `open1`, `open2`, ... and so on.

```js
Vue.component('card', {
  template: `
<div class="card">
  <span v-if="open"><slot/></span>
  <button @click="open = !open">toggle</button>
</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <card>title 1</card>
  <card>title 2</card>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, sorry, i was typing from my phone (updated now), yes i have alot of then, i cant see your idea, could you be more specific?. btw this elements are cards, so i need to show the cards data into a modal

Comment: See my edits. Does the modal have anything to do with this question? I don't know how it fits into your problem.

Comment: the modal will show the card content clicked, so yes, i think you are showing me something else (hide and show elements with v-show and v-if)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. Create the cards data into a array of objects in the data instance
2. Use a v-for to loop through the cards
3. Create a method that capture the card clicked, create a projectSelected value in data

   ```
   <button @click="showModal = !showModal,open(project)">Open</button>
   captureProject(card) {
       this.projectSelected = project;
   },
   ```
4. Show the selected project inside the modal

   {{ projectSelected .title }}